# Como fazer este programa se repetir?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Que comando é útil pra fazer o programa rodar desde o início ao chegar ao final??

```
f=float(input("Digite 0 para retânglo, 1 para triângulo:"))

if f==0:
    a=float(input("valor da altura:"))
    b=float(input("valor da base:"))
    print(a*b/2)
else:
    a=float(input("valor da altura:"))
    b=float(input("valor da base:"))
    print(a*b)
```

Comment: Você quer que programa rode pra sempre, é isso?

Comment: acho que vc ainda ñ viu a linguagem por completo, while talvez seja oq vc quer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o bloco de repetição `while`. A sintanxe do bloco é `while bool:`, onde, ele irá repetir o código enquanto a condição for `True`. Logo o seu programa pode ficar dessa forma:

```
stop = False

while not stop:

    f=float(input("Digite 0 para retângulo, 1 para triângulo:"))

    if f==0:
        a=float(input("valor da altura:"))
        b=float(input("valor da base:"))
        print(a*b/2)
    else:
        a=float(input("valor da altura:"))
        b=float(input("valor da base:"))
        print(a*b)

    if input("Deseja sair (Y/N) ? ").lower() == "y":
        stop = True
```

Como o valor inicialmente da variável `stop` é `False` e eu declarei um `not`, ela terá o valor `True` na sintaxe do `while`.
Caso o usuário digite `"y"` ou `"Y"`, a variável `stop` terá o valor `True`, e na sintaxe do `while`ele terá o valor `False`. Dessa forma ele sai do bloco `while` e fecha o programa caso não exista mais código abaixo.