# Python como repetir meu codigo

Tags: python, loop

gostaria de repetir esse codigo pra nao iterar ele 300 vezes , é um robo pra clicar na tela,queria que ele se repetisse , o codigo é esse ,sou novo aqui e na programação nao se se coloquei certo o formato da pergunta aqui e nao foi como o codigo no vscode mas é basicamente isso hehe

```
import pyautogui


import time




pyautogui.moveTo(28,295,duration=0.5)

pyautogui.click(30,295,duration=0.5)



pyautogui.moveTo(650,220,duration=1)

pyautogui.click(650,220,duration=1)


pyautogui.moveTo(650,670,duration=0.3)

pyautogui.click(650,670,duration=1)
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo Lutgens10,  veja se esta pergunta ( e os links que estão nela) te ajuda: [Como fazer este programa se repetir?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401392/como-fazer-este-programa-se-repetir)

Aconselho você a fazer o nosso [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar o while loop ou o for loop:

```py
import pyautogui
import time

i = 0

while i < 300:

    pyautogui.moveTo(28,295,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(30,295,duration=0.5)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,220,duration=1)
    pyautogui.click(650,220,duration=1)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,670,duration=0.3)
    pyautogui.click(650,670,duration=1)

    i += 1
```

```py
import pyautogui
import time

for _ in range(300):

    pyautogui.moveTo(28,295,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(30,295,duration=0.5)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,220,duration=1)
    pyautogui.click(650,220,duration=1)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,670,duration=0.3)
    pyautogui.click(650,670,duration=1)
```

Comment: obrigado cara muito obrigado

Comment: cara ta dando um erro no console   invalid syntax (<unknow>,line8) pylint(syntax-error)  [8,10]

Comment: a sintaxe da resposta está correta. Sugiro que você compare como você digitou o código aí, com o que está aqui.

Lembrando que vocẽ tem que configurar a ferramenta que está usand para editar código para usar "espaços" e nao "tabs" (ou 'tabuladores' ,   vai saber como está a tradução)

Comment: estou usando o vscode , ele nao deixa fazer o while que merda , nao sei mudar pra espaços hahahah vou pesquisar aqui valeu

Answer (score -6):

```
import pyautogui
import time

i = 0

while i < 300:

    pyautogui.moveTo(28,295,duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.click(30,295,duration=0.5)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,220,duration=1)
    pyautogui.click(650,220,duration=1)

    pyautogui.moveTo(650,670,duration=0.3)
    pyautogui.click(650,670,duration=1)

    i += 1
```

Comment: Além do código não possuir qualquer explicação o que essa resposta tem de diferente da resposta já aceita?